# How to consider Explain plan as good- Oracle 10G

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

When an oracle explained plan is consider good? 
I'm try to refactor a DB Schema, and there are so many query in view and packages that are so slow.

For example, this is one of the most orrible query, and give me this explain plan:

Plan
ALL_ROWSCost: 18,096  Bytes: 17  Cardinality:   1

I don't ask how to fix a query, just how to consider the explain plan as good. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before considering the result of an Explain Plan we need to understand following terminologies,
Cardinality– Estimate of the number of rows coming out of each of the operations.
• Access method – The way in which the data is being accessed, via either a table scan or index 
access. 
• Join method – The method (e.g., hash, sort-merge, etc.) used to join tables with each other. 
• Join type – The type of join (e.g., outer, anti, semi, etc.). 
• Join order – The order in which the tables are joined to each other.
• Partition pruning – Are only the necessary partitions being accessed to answer the query?
• Parallel Execution  – In case of parallel execution, is each operation  in the plan being 
conducted in parallel? Is the right data redistribution method being used?

By reviewing the four key 
elements of: cardinality estimations, access methods, join methods, and join orders; you can determine if the execution plan is the best available plan.
This white paper will help you, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/bi-datawarehousing/twp-explain-the-explain-plan-052011-393674.pdf

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

The cost estimate is oracles educated guess on how many blocks it will need to visit in order to answer your query. Is 18,096 a good number? That depends on what you are doing, how fast your server is and how quick you need it to run. There is little meaning in this number as an absolute value.

If you change the SQL or and indexes and the cost estimate goes down that is a good sign but what really matters is how long when it actually ruins. Oracle can estimate badly at times.

Having said all that it looks a bit high for something that runs while a user waits but reasonable for a batch job.

Comment: I don't think [cost](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/ex_plan.htm#g30946) is clearly related to blocks - "The value of this column does not have any particular unit of measurement; it is merely a weighted value used to compare costs of execution plans."

Comment: Maybe not officially.  But see http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/12/11/cost-is-time/ which indicates that cost is number of single block reads (sreadtim)

Comment: That article says time is derived from cost multiplied by sreadtim.  Sreadtim is related to a single block,
but that doesn't necessarily mean that cost is.  As a quick test, I created a table, set the number of blocks, and did a simple select from the table.  The cost was only 1/4th the number of blocks.  1: `create table test1(a number);` 2: `exec dbms_stats.set_table_stats(user, 'TEST1', numblks => 100000);`
3: `explain plan for select * from test1;` 4: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`